# Can I rewrite this solution to a log growth question with less steps and text?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am working on a textbook exercise:

Given the log growth formula of $\frac{1000}{1+9e^{-0.6t}}$ find how long it takes for the population to reach 900.

The solution provided is 7.3 and I was able to arrive at this. But, reading over my solution I 'feel' like it's got too many steps and text and I just wondered if there was a simpler route to get my answer.

Here's my working:

$$900=\frac{1000}{1+9e^{-0.6t}}$$
$$1000=(900)(1+9e^{-0.6t})$$
$$\frac{1000}{900}-1=9e^{-0.6t}$$

(here is where I think I'm doing thing's 'wrong'. I have a fraction of a fraction on the left side, is there a better way to denote this? Can I somehow use a negative exponent instead of dividing by 9 for example? Or anything else? Or is what I have sound?)

$$\frac{\frac{1000}{900}-1}{9}=e^{-0.6t}$$
$$ln(\frac{1000}{900}-1)-ln9=-0.6t$$

(Again, here I feel like this expression is too cluttered, is there a simpler, less text way to express it?)
$$\frac{ln(\frac{1000}{900}-1)-ln9}{-0.6}=t$$
$$t=7.3$$

More generally, I'm wondering if I'm missing any opportunities to simplify my fraction expressions, either using rules of logs that I've missed or any other means?

Comment: I'd write $e^{0,6t}=\frac{1}{9}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed save some work.

Write
$$
\frac{1000}{900} -1 = \frac{10}{9} -1 = \frac{1}{9}
$$
as soon as it appears.

Then you reach
$$
\frac{1}{81} = e^{-0.6t}
$$
with just one natural logarithm to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks OK,
and there is almost always sevaral other ways, for example,

\begin{align} 
\frac{1000}{1+9e^{-0.6t}}&=900
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\frac{10}{1+9e^{-0.6t}}&=\frac91
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\frac{10-9}{1+9e^{-0.6t}-1}
&=\frac91
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
\frac{1}{9e^{-0.6t}}
&=\frac91
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
e^{0.6t}&=81
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
0.6t&=4\ln 3
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
t&=\tfrac{20}3\,\ln3
\approx 7.324
\tag{7}\label{7}
.
\end{align}